# Unit test: Real database vs. mocking

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I'm unit-testing an asp.net MVC 3 web application which our team is building.

The problem is that we have to mock a lot of things and our unit tests don't cover all webserver and database-related stuff.

Example:

I have a method with the following code:

```
public List<Useraccount> GetUseraccounts(Company company)
{
    return company.Useraccounts.ToList<Useraccount>();
}
```

My developer complains that he has to inject a fake company object he's preparing by himself. He'd like to have a real object from the database.

My question:
Is it possible to use a real database (could also be SQLite/SQLExpress or something) with Unit-Test? Is this useful?
What are the pros and cons?

Without a real database we need to mock too many objects. We can not verify that, for example, such calls are working:

```
Useraccount useraccount = UnitOfWork.UseraccountRepository.Get(u => u.EnableCode == enableCode && u.IsEnabled == false).Single<Useraccount>();
```

Comment: Sounds as if you may be blurring the line between *unit* testing and *integration* testing.

Comment: Meaning what? Real database stuff is for integration testing only?

Comment: What I believe @Forty-Two means is that you should consider two suits of tests. One is about unit testing, testing that your class do what they are supposed to do and mocking out dependencies. Then you can go to the next level of black box / integration testing where you test your services in their entirety but mock out third party services where needed.

Comment: Yes, but I'm actually not able to test method like Useraccount useraccount = UnitOfWork.UseraccountRepository.Get(u => u.EnableCode == enableCode && u.IsEnabled == false).Single<Useraccount>(); because of the EF.

Answer (score 2):

Testing against a real database is integration testing, not unit testing. You can still run the integration tests in the same manner as unit tests - that is, run them via nunit or mstest or whatever, and via a command line or some such on your build server - but there are a couple of extra steps:

1. You need to setup the test data, inject it into the database, run the test, then remove the test data again. In an ideal world, you'd create a test database at the start of your integration test run, then run all tests, then remove it after all integration tests are finished. This can be impractical though.
2. Your integration tests will run much more slowly than unit tests. Be prepared for this by running them, for example, nightly in a build server job.

In terms of using SqlLite or whatever, i'd say not to, use the exact type of database you're using in the real world, otherwise it's not a trustworthy test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Basically we first'd like to "complete" the unit tests. My feeling is that they're incomplete because we're not able to test a lot of lines in our code because of the Entity framework.

Comment: I'd say it's a rare application that can cover all (or even most) lines of data access code using only unit tests. Having said that, are you sure EF is the issue, and that the code couldn't be reworked to be more unit-testable?

Answer (score 1):

try to use [Effort](http://effort.codeplex.com/) tool . [Effort](http://effort.codeplex.com/) is a powerful tool that enables a convenient way to create automated tests for Entity Framework based applications. 
It is basically an ADO.NET provider that executes all the data operations on a lightweight in-process main memory database instead of a traditional external database. It provides some intuitive helper methods too that make really easy to use this provider with existing ObjectContext or DbContext classes. A simple addition to existing code might be enough to create data driven tests that can run without the presence of the external database.